# Querying data from ROW_NUMBER result

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I am trying to query data based on the ROW_NUMBER() function.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS CountRow,
ProductId, ProductName, Tracklink, ProductImage, TrackPrice FROM ProductDetails;
```

I have my row with the numbers in CountRow column.  Now I want to query this Alias to find rows for example between 31 and 40. But I get an error saying CountRow does not exist.

How can I overcome this issue?

thanks....

Comment: wrap this query and select from that... do not try it all in the same where clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS CountRow,
ProductId, ProductName, Tracklink, ProductImage, TrackPrice FROM ProductDetails) AS A
WHERE CountRow BETWEEN 31 AND 40
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How is this any different from @Shark answer 5 minutes ago?

Comment: It doesn't have it's linebreaks (?)

Comment: No body had answered when I open the page. I tested to make sure I am posting correct answer for you and during that time two had replied. I saw them only after clicking the Add Answer button. Yes there is no line break but almost same.

Answer (score 4):

You can't reference an alias in the `WHERE` clause.  Wrap it in a subquery and you'll be fine:

```
select *
from
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS CountRow,
    ProductId, ProductName, Tracklink, ProductImage, TrackPrice FROM ProductDetails
) a
where CountRow between 31 and 40
```

Answer (score 3):

If your DBMS support cte you can do it like this:

```
;WITH CTE
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS CountRow,
        ProductId, 
        ProductName, 
        Tracklink, 
        ProductImage, 
        TrackPrice 
    FROM 
        ProductDetails
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    CTE.CountRow between 31 and 40
```